# What do you call 2d images animated or not transposed over a video?

Tags: word-request

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_-aLbO1G6k

What do you call 2d images animated or not transposed over a video?

Is it called a cutout, or is it something else, and it's can't be applied to this, since cutout implies the 2d image is not animated, and is there maybe a more appropriate word or term used for this kind of sfx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[overlay](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overlay)** from Merriam-Webster:

> *noun*
> **c :** a transparent sheet containing graphic matter to be superimposed on another sheet

This definition is from graphic design before computers, but the same term applies in computer aided design, even if it isn't a physical sheet.

FWIW, the verb is "overlay" or "superimpose".